# Multiple foreign keys in one to many relationship - SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am a newbie in SQL Alchemy and I need a help to implement the following relationship :

I have two tables **Trends** and **ClosestTrends** and I want to declare two one-to-many relationships :

[Tables relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJKhb.png)

In SQL, it would be :

```
ALTER TABLE "closest_trends" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("id_trend_ref") REFERENCES "trends" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE "closest_trends" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("id_trend_close") REFERENCES "trends" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I tried the following implementation :

```
class Trends(Base):
    __tablename__ = "trends"
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint(
            "name", "id_region", "language_iso", name="name_id_region_language"
        ),
    )
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    .
    .
    .
    closest_trends = relationship("ClosestTrends", backref="Trends")
   
    def __str__(self):
        return "Trends"



class ClosestTrends(Base):
    __tablename__ = "closest_trends"
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint(
            "id_trend_ref", "id_trend_close", name="id_trend_ref_id_trend_close"
        ),
    )
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    .
    .
    .
    
    id_trend_ref = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("trends.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False
    )
    id_trend_close = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("trends.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False
    )
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "ClosestTrends"
```

I does not work and I am receiving the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join
> condition between parent/child tables on relationship
> Trends.closest_trends - there are multiple foreign key paths linking
> the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of
> those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key
> reference to the parent table.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this ?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't get it. Both foreign keys are the same and they aren't even nullable. Isn't that an issue with design before it becomes an SQLA issue?

Comment: It seems to me that it would be better to have a many-to-many association table of related trends, and you'd just store the foreign key of the trend once

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. There are more than 40 tables in our database and there are some constraints that forced us to follow this design and have these two relations. It worked very well in SQL but with SqlAlchemy it's a bit difficult to implement.

Comment: Ugh :P Ok, well `relationship` takes a `foreign_keys` argument as a list, I think, so try `closest_trends = relationship("ClosestTrends", backref="Trends", foreign_keys=['closest_trends.id'])`

Comment: I tried to use foreign_keys as well in `relationship`. Concerning the scenario you propose, I am getting : sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column-based expression object expected for argument 'foreign_keys'; got: 'closest_trends.id', type <class 'str'> ,  I tried ClosestTrends.id as well and It didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your solution is written in official site.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths
according to official site, I implement like this.

```
class Trends(Base):
    __tablename__ = "trends"
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint(
            "name", "id_region", "language_iso", name="name_id_region_language"
        ),
    )
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    .
    .
    .
    # closest_trends = relationship("ClosestTrends", backref="Trends")
   
    def __str__(self):
        return "Trends"

class ClosestTrends(Base):
    __tablename__ = "closest_trends"
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint(
            "id_trend_ref", "id_trend_close", name="id_trend_ref_id_trend_close"
        ),
    )
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    .
    .
    .
    
    id_trend_ref = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("trends.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False
    )
    id_trend_close = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("trends.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False
    )
    
    trend_ref = relationship("Trends", foreign_keys=[id_trend_ref])
    trend_close = relationship("Trends", foreign_keys=[id_trend_close])

    def __str__(self):
```